# in printf (in c) what is the order of displaying variable and push into stack

Tags: c

Suppose i have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
main()
{
   int a,b,c;
    b=1;
    c=2;

    printf("%d\n",10,b=20,b=30,c=50,c=100);
    printf("%d\n",b);
    printf("%d\n",c);
}
```

o/p-10,20,50
how did the value of b became 20,not 30 ..and also the same for c?

Comment: you have both undefined and implementation dependent behavior. i.e. it won't work

Comment: It is not related to printf. The order of evaluation of function arguments is implementation dependent. It can be from left to right or  right to left or any other order.

Comment: it will start to push in stack from right to left(generally)

Comment: This is undefined which is due to sequencing in printf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of evaluation of argument expressions and their pushing on the stack are different things.

The order of evaluation of argument expressions are unspecified in C. So it might be that at first b = 20 will be evaluated and then b = 30 or vice versa.

The order of placing arguments in the stack is the following: the right most argument is placed first.

Comment: +1'd,To clarify more--->shouldn't it be `The order of placing arguments in the stack is the following: the right most argument is placed at the bottom.`

Comment: It depends on the ABI - some don't even use the stack, or use a mixture of registers and stack.

Comment: Even worse, this is multiple assignments to one location without intervening sequence point, so it is undefined behaviour.